# How is String in switch statement more efficient than corresponding if-else statement?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, switch-statement

[Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) says

> The Java compiler generates generally more efficient bytecode from switch statements that use String objects than from chained if-then-else statements.

AFAIK even String in switch uses `.equals()` internally in a case sensitive manner. So what efficiency do they mean in this context. Faster compilation? Less bytecodes ? better performance?

Comment: helpful link :http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx

Comment: BTW, apologies to all; I was apparently writing while asleep last night and just wasn't making the connection to a hash-based dispatch table. Yes, that makes perfect sense, not just for non-integer values but for widely-spaced sparse values. "Caution: To avoid damage to reputation, engage brain before putting fingers in gear."

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Using a switch statement is faster than equals (but only noticeably when there are more than just a few strings) because it first uses the `hashCode` of the string that `switch` on to determine the subset of the strings that could possibly match. If more than one string in the case labels has the same hashCode, the JVM will perform sequential calls to `equals` and even if there is only one string in the case labels that a hashCode, the JVM needs to call `equals` to confirm that the string in the case label is really equal to the one in the switch expression.

The runtime performance of a switch on String objects is comparable to a lookup in a `HashMap`.

This piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Bar";
    switch (s) {
    case "Foo":
        System.out.println("Foo match");
        break;
    case "Bar":
        System.out.println("Bar match");
        break;
    }
}
```

Is internally compiled to and executed like this piece of code:

(not literally, but if you decompile both pieces of code you see that the exact same sequence of actions occurs)

```
final static int FOO_HASHCODE = 70822; // "Foo".hashCode();
final static int BAR_HASHCODE = 66547; // "Bar".hashCode();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Bar";
    switch (s.hashCode()) {
    case FOO_HASHCODE:
        if (s.equals("Foo"))
            System.out.println("Foo match");
        break;
    case BAR_HASHCODE:
        if (s.equals("Bar"))
            System.out.println("Bar match");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: they could also use a trie implementation

Comment: More details on internal compilation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10

Answer (score 21):

In **general**, switch statements are better because they are (loosely speaking) `O(1)`, while a chain of `if-else` is `O(n)`

Having `n` conditions could result in up to `n` comparisons using a chained `if-else` statements.

A switch statement can "jump" directly to the appropriate condition (like a map) or to the default case, making it `O(1)`.

Comment: This makes sense as per explanation @Erwin Bolwidt has provided.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bytecode fragment generated from example in the docs:

```
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/String.hashCode ()I
    LOOKUPSWITCH
      -2049557543: L2
      -1984635600: L3
      -1807319568: L4
```

using LOOKUPSWITCH  has better perfomance compared to if-else logic

Comment: LOOKUPSWITCH is a bytecode instruction that has always been there. It is used instead of TABLESWITCH when the integer values it switches on are widely spaced apart. As you see in the assembly, it doesn't switch on the string itself, but on the hashCode of the string. You need to show the bytecode at L2, L3 or L4 as well: there you'll see that a call to String.equals is needed to verify that the string is really the same.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt But interestingly, TABLESWITCH is not necessarily what it sounds like: with default settings, under 17 cases, it is translated to series of cmp/je (i.e. if/goto) in assembly. With 18 cases or more, it becomes a real table switch at the assembly level too.

Comment: Interesting. Also noticed that (at least) the Eclipse compiler doesn't emit a TABLESWITCH even when you switch on strings with successive hashCodes ("A", "B", "C", etc.).