# Re-Initializing a Variable as a Constant

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, constants

I am new to Java. I want to know whether there is a way to re-initialize a declared global variable as a constant later after using it as a variable ... That is because after doing some work with a declared variable  I want to use it in a Switch case statement...

```
class A {
    int x;
    int y;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();

        System.out.println(a.x);
        a.y = 3;
        a.x = 5;
        switch (a.y) {
            case a.x:// Something
        }
    }
}
```

this is an example for What I need... print statement mentions, that I need to do something with variable x. later I want to use it in a Switch case statement. I don't want to use x after switch case statement... Please help me...

Comment: I dont think you can use `a.x` or even `a.getX()` in a case statement. It accepts only constants.

Comment: yes... that's what I want to do... I want to use a.x in a case statement... so for that I want to re-initialize it as a constant... My question is, Is there a way  to do that ?

Comment: Yes, do not use [switch-case](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), use `if-elseif-else`

Comment: can't you make `int x;` `final`?

Comment: Also needs to be static...?

Comment: @Adam yes, `static final int x;` would work.

Comment: @A4L yes it is, But I wanted to make it Simple than that... yes, Now feels the only way to handle it is if-else statements...

Comment: @Absurd-Mind No, I don't want to make it final at declaration step... I want to make it final(a constant) after doing some works with it as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know whether there is a way to re-initialize a declared global variable as a constant later after using it as a variable...

No, there isn't. (Java also doesn't have global variables; looking at your code, `x` and `y` are *instance data members*. The closest thing Java has to global variables are `public static` [aka "class"] data members in public classes.)

> That is because after doing some work with a declared variable I want to use it in a Switch case statement...

You can't if the case values (`a.x`, in your case) aren't constants. Instead, you have to use `if/else if/else`:

```
class A {
    int x;
    int y;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();

        System.out.println(a.x);
        a.y = 3;

        if (a.y == a.x) {
            // ...
        }
        else if (a.y == something_else) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Java also doesn't have global variables; " isn't static variables globle ?

Comment: @whiletrue No they are not, public static are closer, but they still aren't properly global and usable everywhere

Comment: @whiletrue: `public static` data members in classes are *close* to being globals, if the classes that they're in are `public`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the answer is you cannot do this in Java.

The "things" after case need to be constants.
In Java 7 or later, you can also use strings as case labels.

[Switch statement Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. To use something as a case in a `switch`, it must be a constant known at compile time. If you want to set it based on a variable (i.e. at run time), there is no way it could be known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

You can only switch on compile time constants. I think what you're trying to achieve could be done with a simple if statement.

```
if (a.y == a.x) {
    // do stuff.
}
```

Since constants in Java are compile time, "re-initializing" does not make sense as a concept.

Comment: yes, But I wanted to make it simple by using Switch-Case statement. Now feels can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, when you write a `switch` statement, the compiler must be able to tell *at compile time* what the values of the `case` choices will be.  If you want to set up a `switch` where one of the `case` choices will be a value determined at runtime--sorry, you can't.  Use `if` statements instead.

Traditionally, `switch` statements (and `CASE` statements in other languages) were used to set up jump tables.  That is, in a C program:

```
switch (n) {
    case 1:
        ...code
    case 2:
        ...code
    case 14:
        ...code
}
```

The compiler would set up a table with at least 14 entries.  The #1, #2, and #14 entries in the table would contain code addresses of places that it would jump to.  (The others would have the address of a "default" location.)  Then, the code generated by the compiler wouldn't be a series of "compare-to-1, if equal-then else compare-to-2, if equal-then else ..." kinds of instructions; instead, after making sure `n` was in the range of the table, it would index into the table, find the address, and jump directly there.  Very efficient.  Java does the same thing if you give it an integer (for `String`s, it can create a jump table based on the hash code, but it still has to compare the strings for equality--thanks to @ErwinBolwidt for providing more information on this).

The point behind all this, though, is that in order to generate the table, the compiler has to know the values ahead of time.  So what you're asking for isn't supported, at least in C or Java.  (I think some languages do relax this and allow variable values in `case`, but they may all or mostly be interpreted languages.)

Comment: Java also creates a jump table for integers, but also for Strings (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110707/how-is-string-in-switch-statement-more-efficient-than-corresponding-if-else-stat/22110821#22110821)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks for the link.  I thought maybe it could use the hash code; I just wasn't sure if it actually did.

Comment: Yes , I got it... This is only a Opinion... If java can be developed to use a variable in a switch case statement that'll be very helpful.