# Using Strings in switch case

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Can anyone explain

> Java compiler generates more efficient byte code for String in `switch` statement than chained `if-else-if` statements

What does this mean?

It is written in Java Documentation.

Comment: That means that using Switch statements is more efficient/better. Which part of that statement don't you understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is String in switch statement more efficient than corresponding if-else statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110707/how-is-string-in-switch-statement-more-efficient-than-corresponding-if-else-stat)

Comment: At most one switch can match a given expression, so the switch can jump straight to a matching case (if any), rather than having to evaluate all of the cases until a match is found.